# Existence of file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 for PID 1 on the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Does the Linux kernel **always** provide file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 for the PID 1 process passed on boot with `init=...` or implicitly `/sbin/init`(`/etc/init`, `/bin/init`, `/bin/sh`)? Do they refer to the system console `/dev/console`? What happens if `/dev` is not provided on init, but has to be set up by the init system?

Answer (score 1):

They're hooked to the console by `kernel_init_freeable`. The console is opened and duplicated directly without going through `/dev`.

```
    /* Open the /dev/console on the rootfs, this should never fail */
    if (sys_open((const char __user *) "/dev/console", O_RDWR, 0) < 0)
            pr_err("Warning: unable to open an initial console.\n");

    (void) sys_dup(0);
    (void) sys_dup(0);
```

Comment: Could you include information going back as far as to kernel version 2.4 (the code included in your answer is in effect starting from 2.6.34 [commit 2bd3a997befc226ab4b504f05c5cbba305f3e0e6 "init: Open /dev/console from rootfs" in mainline]) and how the choice of an early userspace (initrd, initramfs, etc.) determines the fds?